# Configure diff table name in hibernate for MySQL and SQL server for the same entity

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate, orm

I have an entity with table name "Transaction". While creating connection using spring orm and hibernate, on startup it successfully creates tables in MySQL but being "Transaction" a keyword in SQL server, it fails on startup.
I cannot change the table name in the code as there is a lot of ripple effects. Hence is there a way where I can define the table name as Transaction in java and intercept or configure in such a way that hibernate while connecting to SQL server escapes the keyword and queries it as "[Transaction]" (escaping it using [])

Comment: You can probably use a naming strategy for that: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy

Comment: Thanks. implementing PhysicalNamingStrategy did the trick. Please do post it as an answer, for me to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a naming strategy as explained in this article: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy

```
public class CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy implements PhysicalNamingStrategy {
    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(final Identifier identifier, final JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
        return Identifier.toIdentifier(**your table name**);
    }

    // Other methods
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try one of the following way:

```
@Table(name = "`Transaction`");

@Table(name = "\"Transaction\"")
```

or by setting a property:

```
hibernate.auto_quote_keyword=true
```

Comment: This is already in place. Please read the question again. My ask is a bit more complex

Comment: My bad! You can try one of the following way: @Table(name = "\`Transaction\`"); @Table(name = "\"Transaction\"")  or hibernate.auto_quote_keyword=true

Comment: Please [edit] your answer instead of adding comments.